# Trying to get results from a powershell script executed through Intune MDM

Tags: powershell, azure, audit, intune

I've run a simple audit powershell script on my auto-enrolled MDM Intune Devices via Azure AD.

Can anyone give me pointers as to where the results of these scripts are stored?
It's really baffling me and googling is just bringing me round in circles without any clear answers.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From my similar reddit thread!

Ah, for sure!
https://oliverkieselbach.com/2017/11/29/deep-dive-microsoft-intune-management-extension-powershell-scripts/

I just came across this link that discuss in length that the results of scripts are stored to a temp file and then deleted after execution. But that the results are saved in the local registry.

I wasn't aware I should create an object or use powershell to save to Azure AD; I assumed the Intune managing of opwershell would make that simpler. I was wrong. Thanks a mill though, I'll take a look at using powershell to create an Azure AD object to track my results!